# Update element on updating react state array

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am confused in updating element with React.useState()
I am creating dynamic calculator, where you can add fields, so I cannot use one state per result of category, so I created an object contains results by Id of category, and categories can be added there.
`let [results, setResults] = React.useState({});`
Then every time when user adds a product

```
for (const category of product.categories) {
  results[category.id] = 0;
```

When I am updating result for some category, it is gets updated:

```
setResults(newResults => {
  newResults[categoryId] = mult * sum * quantity;
  return newResults;
})
```

But my element in the table keeps showing zero (inital value)`<TableCell align="right"><p>{results[category.id]}</p></TableCell>`

Upd: here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/cbJzFC8t
[Page looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMmkW.png)

Comment: can you show code a little bit more hard to understand right now.

Comment: I suspect the problem is you have to totally create new object as React uses referential comparison and `newResults` doesn't differ. Try replacing your return with: `return { ...newResults }`. If it works, I'll write proper answer with detailed explanation.

Comment: Just replaced with `return { ...newResults };`. Still no element update

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a new variable

```
setResults(oldResults=> {
  let newResults = oldResults[categoryId]
  newResults = mult * sum * quantity;
  return newResults;
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help, the results are updated but the element is not.